# Trouble with fancontrol/pwm_config

Tags: hardware, fan

Asus Q551LN

sensors output:

```
 coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Package id 0:  +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 0:        +28.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
    Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_haswell-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +29.5°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +33.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:       -1 RPM
temp1:        +33.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.60 V  (min =  +0.60 V, max =  +1.20 V)
```

pwm_config output:

```
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is nouveau
   hwmon2 is pch_haswell
   hwmon3 is asus
   hwmon4 is coretemp

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon3/pwm1           current value: 255

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon3/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

I've had this issue of my fan not working properly on Manjaro, Arch, Fedora, and Ubuntu. pwmconfig says that I have no working fan sensors. I tried ignoring this and writing a configuration file for fancontrol, but I couldn't get it to work. The cpu_fan sensors will either say -1 or 25500 RPM after awakening from hibernate. If I start my laptop while plugged in the fans will be around 2500 RPM or off. Sensors-detect only finds coretemp and because pwmconfig doesn't think I have fan sensors it doesn't generate a config file. Also from switching to Ubuntu from Arch, the place where the pwm that controls the fan switched from hwmon3 to hwmon4 and I don't know if that is any indication as to what could be wrong.

Fancontrol configuration that I tried to write:
Fancontrol says Enabling PWM on fans...
Starting automatic fan control..., but doesn't progress

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon4=devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi
DEVNAME=hwmon4=asus
FCTEMPS=hwmon4/pwm1=hwmon4/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon4/pwm1=hwmon4/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon4/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon4/pwm1=55
MINSTART=hwmon4/pwm1=75
MINSTOP=hwmon4/pwm1=55
MINPWM=0
MAXPWM=255
```

sensors-detect output after saying yes for everything:

```
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 
Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!
```

So it only finds coretemp, but shouldn't asus be one since that's where the fan control is?

Output of lsmod | grep -i asus:

```
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    24576  2 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915
asus_wireless          16384  0
```

Any help appreciated.

Update:

For now I have given up on fancontrol working. I upgraded to Cosmic Cuttlefish to see if that would solve any problems, it didn't. Since I lose control of my fans after my laptop wakes up from suspend, I turned off suspend. As this isn't really a fix any help is still appreciated.

Comment: Did sensors-detect indicate that you should load some modules?  A line near the end like "To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:..."

Comment: Updated post with sensors-detect output

Comment: There are a couple of modules with the word 'asus' in their name, but I'd be guessing to tell you which ones to include.  You could `sudo modprobe asus-laptop` (and `sudo modprobe -r asus-laptop`) to see if one or more of them helps.  I would suggest you include the coretemp module anyhow - the source for it is in the sensors section of the sources "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-14-generic/include/config/sensors/coretemp.h"

Comment: but you should first `lsmod | grep -i asus` to determine what has loaded automatically

Comment: Updated post with lsmod | grep -i asus output

Comment: Running `sudo modprobe asus-laptop` is good to the next boot, or you could remove it with `modprobe -r` - I really don't know what is contained in the module.